# Rewrite conditions and rules in Virtual host or .htaccess? Which is preferred?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am using `apache 2.4` and hosting an `angular2` application. I have written the `rewrite rules and conditions` in my virtual host itself, but I wonder if I should use an `.htaccess` file. What are the benefits of using one over the other?

> Edit: Added .htaccess

I tried with the implementation of `.htaccess` for angular2 and it seems that I have to manually paste the `.htaccess` in the `dist` folder. Which would be bad. But still, I ask this for a generic application. Which configuration should be preferred? Do the configuration in `virtual host` or have a separate `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at this [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) and this pretty much cleared my confusion.

The document recommends not to use `.htaccess` if there is no frequent need to change the `rewrite configurations`.

**There could be a need to change these, in cases like:**

> .htaccess files should be used in a case where the content providers need to make configuration changes to the server on a per-directory basis, but do not have root access on the server system. In the event that the server administrator is not willing to make frequent configuration changes, it might be desirable to permit individual users to make these changes in .htaccess files for themselves. This is particularly true, for example, in cases where ISPs are hosting multiple user sites on a single machine, and want their users to be able to alter their configuration.

**Why not to use?**

> 1. The first of these is performance. When AllowOverride is set to allow the use of .htaccess files, httpd will look in every directory for .htaccess files. Thus, permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit, whether or not you actually even use them! Also, the .htaccess file is loaded every time a document is requested.
> 2. In the case of RewriteRule directives, in .htaccess context these
>      regular expressions must be re-compiled with every request to the
>      directory, whereas in main server configuration context they are
>      compiled once and cached.